# Interpreting Basic JavaScript results

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure what this code will produce? I'm assuming that the array "t" is already defined and filled.

```
var j, s;
for (var j = 0; j < 34; j++){
    s += (t[j] * 4) / 5;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is the contents of `t`?

Comment: It'll produce the sum of the array members each having been multiplied by 4, then divided by 5.

Comment: Why don't you just test it in your browser console? Just fill `t` with some values. Here, take this one: `var t = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];`. ;)

Comment: We can't know what it produces if we don't know the value of `t` Is it for a homework ? :)

Comment: I think it weaponizes the user's browser. Also... have you run it?

Comment: ditto on Zeta's point, Firebug does wonders

Comment: Can you please accept an answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. It helps a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`s` will be `NaN` since it was not initialized with a numerical value. `undefined + x` (where `x` is a number) is always `NaN`.

Comment: *"`undefined + x` is always `NaN`."* ...`undefined + "foo"; // "undefinedfoo"` ... `undefined + [123]; // "undefined123"` ... `undefined + {}; // "undefined[object Object]"` ... and so on. You probably mean to assume that `x` is a number.

Comment: Lol, this was left wide open for nitpicks